# Is it possible to restrict the range of select all/Ctrl+A?

Tags: javascript, html, selection, contenteditable

I am working on a website where I would like to be able to display a box containing syntax-highlighted source code for the user to copy. When I click on the box, giving it focus (Chrome shows its focus outline), and type <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, the text of the entire page is selected, whereas I would like only the syntax-highlighted source code within the box to be selected.

Is it possible to restrict the range of select all/<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to only the text within the box, preferably without using an <iframe>?

My first thought was to try [`contenteditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690.aspx). When I click in the box and the editor caret appears, typing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> selects only the text within the box, as desired, but it also allows the user to change the code, and I think that the editor-interface aspect of making the box `contenteditable` will be confusing to users. If I wrap the source code text within a <div> having `contenteditable="false"` within the <div> having `contenteditable="true"`, then the source code text is read-only, but typing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> selects the text of the entire page again.

Here is a test page: http://jsfiddle.net/5crgL/

Comment: override what happens on [ctrl]+[a] using jwerty? => http://keithcirkel.co.uk/jwerty/

Comment: It's kinda called "Select All", so limiting the range wouldn't exactly be "select all" any more, would it? ;)

Comment: Why not use something like a disabled textarea?

Comment: @Linus: I want the text to be syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `document.createRange();` method to select the text from a particular element.
and to handle the ctrl+a you can use the jQuery `keydown` method and can call the JS code to select the DIV text.

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

please see `jsfiddle` here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5crgL/3/).

Comment: The only problem with your solution is that no matter where the user is, it only selects the text in the container. There should probably be a mouse listener to get the mouse position and only grab the container text if the mouse is hovering inside/over the container.

Comment: for this you can use jQuery `is(':hover')` to detect if mouse hover over DIV. please find update `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/5crgL/5/

Comment: Also you match against a certain key-combination, but hotkeys can differ. Mac for example uses cmd + a or users could even configure their own hotkeys.

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows. On Mac, there is an issue where this doesn't work with ⌘A, but I think that that will just require a small tweak.

Comment: Yes you can adjust the code by identifying the os and browser.

Comment: Chrome gives the message: `Selection.addRange() is deprecated and will be removed from Chrome`. A simple solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260617/selection-addrange-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-from-chrome).