# Selection.addRange() is deprecated and will be removed from Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, editor, deprecated, aloha-editor

I recently noticed the following message in chrome's console log, while using [aloha editor](http://www.alohaeditor.org/):

> aloha.js:14579 - The behavior that Selection.addRange() merges existing Range and the specified Range is deprecated and will be removed in M58, around April 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632 for more details.

While trying to find a replacement, i couldn't find anything besides that they are going to remove it, so i would like to know what are the alternatives for Selection.addRange() to get rid of this message.

Answer (score 39):

The trick is to use `removeAllRanges()` on your selection before adding your new range using `addRange(range)`. Here is an example when using it to select all content of `elem`:

```
selection = window.getSelection();    // Save the selection.
range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(elem);
selection.removeAllRanges();          // Remove all ranges from the selection.
selection.addRange(range);            // Add the new range.
```

Comment: This is an incredible insight not seen in many docs I've read. Thank you!