# Selection::addRange very slow in large DOM

Tags: javascript

Is there any alternative to `document.getSelection().addRange()`?

In a content editable frame containing `div`s, it gets slower as we go down the `div`s.

Comment: Did you find any way to improve the speed? As far as I can tell, it is just slow on large DOMs.

Comment: Here is a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138439

Answer (score 1):

Are you running [`removeAllRanges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges) first? The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443101/8379720) make it seem like that call is required / recommended.

An example script from the MDN article:

```
/* Select all STRONG elements in an HTML document */

var strongs = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
var s = window.getSelection();

if(s.rangeCount > 0) s.removeAllRanges();

for(var i = 0; i < strongs.length; i++) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(strongs[i]);
  s.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: yes. removeAllRanges is called first. Also taking first Range object, calling deleteContents and then doing setStart and setEnd for that range doesnot help