# Bootstrap modal CTRL+A selects all text in the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to force Bootstrap modal to select just the text in the modal?
When hitting CTRL+A. it selects all the text on the page,  outside the modal
I can add a textarea, but it will not be as nice, and I will have to fight it to fit in the modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal({show: true});
  });

});
```

```css
/* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>SOME TEXT IN THE BACKGROUND, THIS TEXT WILL ALSO BE SELECTED</p>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
   ### CLICK HERE, then HIT CTRL A to select all the story below:####
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lectus metus, condimentum at tortor vitae, pellentesque convallis urna. Maecenas tristique in nulla a vulputate. Nullam orci arcu, maximus et nisi quis, maximus elementum eros. Vivamus pulvinar finibus sapien at porttitor. Mauris eu elit sodales, vulputate leo dapibus, dapibus nisl. Proin tincidunt, tortor vitae varius pharetra, est elit commodo velit, eu fermentum sem lorem sit amet nunc. Fusce malesuada a mi sit amet eleifend. Suspendisse mauris nulla, laoreet et euismod non, posuere non ante.

Integer eleifend massa velit, non auctor magna finibus vel. Fusce in diam eget ligula sagittis eleifend. Duis tincidunt porta ex, sed egestas sapien tincidunt non. Cras scelerisque gravida semper. Aenean tristique augue quis mi sagittis rhoncus. Donec et mi orci. Integer dignissim quam a varius pulvinar. Morbi porttitor turpis neque, ac egestas erat accumsan ac. Etiam mollis sit amet felis euismod convallis.

Nam at lorem varius lacus semper consectetur non a purus. Integer imperdiet eget enim pharetra suscipit. Pellentesque vel dolor vestibulum, tincidunt erat at, dictum purus. Donec faucibus nibh quis nisi faucibus, eget dignissim nisi porta. Aenean id risus condimentum, rutrum purus a, convallis enim. Pellentesque pellentesque augue et venenatis gravida. Suspendisse eu consectetur diam. Cras pretium felis non ligula varius hendrerit. Aenean volutpat mollis ante, sit amet pharetra neque pretium eget. Vivamus est nisl, hendrerit sit amet fermentum vel, lobortis a nisl.

Donec euismod augue non quam volutpat venenatis. Phasellus ultricies porttitor tortor, placerat rutrum eros semper quis. Ut ut velit at sapien feugiat tincidunt a volutpat metus. Morbi lorem tortor, lacinia in gravida eu, ornare ac libero. Maecenas quis purus non eros euismod viverra. Nullam vitae ornare sem. Sed porttitor quam id iaculis suscipit. Nulla sodales sem sed nisl cursus gravida. Nunc id mauris orci. Morbi blandit elit quis sem cursus iaculis. Fusce finibus, nibh id ullamcorper dictum, orci tortor tincidunt orci, in pretium quam lacus ut turpis. Quisque in euismod lacus, et laoreet nisi.

Proin feugiat urna malesuada, eleifend purus congue, vehicula lorem. Aliquam venenatis augue hendrerit, tristique turpis vel, finibus mi. In eleifend est ac pretium fringilla. Sed ultrices sit amet sem in sollicitudin. Aenean eu odio non lorem suscipit imperdiet ac a quam. Sed id libero nec velit viverra facilisis. Cras venenatis pretium tellus, id fermentum elit sagittis nec. Duis non diam ac enim lobortis tempor sit amet gravida tellus. Quisque sagittis scelerisque fermentum. Morbi suscipit sed ipsum a vehicula. Nullam at euismod est, vel sollicitudin diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec felis nibh, porttitor sed felis ut, interdum gravida nunc. Suspendisse tristique nulla tellus, id auctor massa suscipit vitae. In volutpat enim sit amet libero mattis aliquam. Etiam tempus laoreet massa, eu feugiat enim ultrices sit amet. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: select just the text in the modal? what do you mean by that?

Comment: CTRL+A selects all text in the page not only the text in the modal

Comment: no its just copying modal texts

Comment: no, and title, and anything in background. see edit.

Comment: its not copying the background page text i did check whats happening ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553251/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-range-of-select-all-ctrla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible...

In html

```html
<div>

    <p>Content not to be copied</p>

    <!-- Tab index is very important. It allows the content to be focusable -->
    <div id="copy-target" tabindex="0">
        <p>Content to be copied</p>
        <p>Another content to be copied</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

In js

```js
const copyTarget = document.getElementById("copy-target");

copyTarget.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    const isControlPressed = e.getModifierState("Control");
    const isAPressed = e.keyCode === 65; // Key code for 'A'

    if (isControlPressed && isAPressed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        const sel = window.getSelection(); // Get the selection from the window
        range = document.createRange(); // Create a range object
        range.selectNodeContents(copyTarget); // Set the range to the contents of the copyTarget
        sel.removeAllRanges(); // Remove all ranges from selection (if any)
        sel.addRange(range); // Add range to the selection.
        // document.execCommand("copy") // Copy the selected range
    }
})
```

For this to work however, you'll need to focus on the `copyTarget` element (In this case, your modal)

Here's a link to my pen demonstrating this... https://codepen.io/kwameopareasiedu/pen/GRgNMbP

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to let people select all so they can copy the text, a workaround might be to use something like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com).

Comment: Not a bad idea, but i really don't want to add more lib , im all about anti-library :)