# how can I control the scope of a select all action in HTML/Angular?

Tags: html, angular

This may be a silly question, but some websites, depending where my cursor currently is, when I *select all* (`ctrl+a`), it selects only a portion of the page.

Obviously, I understand how this works for `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements. But is there a *simple* way to control the behavior of that *select all*?

I understand I can capture key events, etc. but I just wondering if there is a HTML built-in attribute or behavior.

Comment: Maybe the css property: `user-select: none` would be what you're looking for.

Comment: interesting @AskYous , I didn't know about that CSS property. However, that's not really what I want. At least I don't think or I don't understand how to use it.
When I am in a `<input>` element and hit `ctrl+a`, it selects the whole input. I was just editing a bug in Jira and noticed that their advanced editor allowed me to hit `ctrl+a` inside a code block and it would only select the code block. As far as I can tell, there are no `<input>` or `<textarea>` in their code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553251/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-range-of-select-all-ctrla

Comment: The first comment for the accepted answer has what you're looking for.

Comment: @Train thanks for the pointer. That's exactly what I was looking for. Of course, that's also exactly what I was afraid of: it's not that simple. Thanks for the info. I'll keep it tucked for future use.